# Getting rid of html tags in python when scraping

Tags: python, html

So I'm trying to scrape the a box score for an NBA game from ESPN. I tried to get the names first but I'm having a difficult time getting rid of the html tags.

I've tried using

```
get_text(), .text(), .string_strip()
```

but they keep giving me errors.

Here's the code I'm working with right now.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url= "http://scores.espn.com/nba/boxscore?gameId=400900407"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")

name = []
for row in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        player_name = row.find('td', attrs={'class': 'name'})
        name.append(player_name)
print(name)
```

Comment: You say errors. what errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `player_name.text` should work, but the problem is that sometimes `row.find('td', attrs={'class': 'name'}` is empty. Try like this:

```
if player_name:
     name.append(player_name.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve this like that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url= "http://scores.espn.com/nba/boxscore?gameId=400900407"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")

name = []
for row in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    try:
        player_name = row.select('td.name span')[0].text
        name.append(player_name)
    except:
        pass
print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

My code for your reference

```
import requests

from pyquery import PyQuery as pyq

url= "http://scores.espn.com/nba/boxscore?gameId=400900407"
r = requests.get(url)
doc = pyq(r.content)
print([h.text() for h in doc('.abbr').items()])
```